# Como saber el número de veces que se ejecuta un ciclo en php

Tags: php

Por ejemplo: Si tengo un ciclo while con la siguientes instrucciones, se ejecutaría 5 veces, bueno la idea es emprimir una variable donde muestre el numero 5 que son las veces que se ejecutaría.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 5) {
    echo $i++; 
}
```

Comment: imprime `$i`,  ¿cual es tu problema?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y porque tu codigo no lo hace?

Answer (score 2):

prueba cambiando el numero 5 por una variable que tenga almacenado el numero maximo.

```
$i = 1; $max = 5;

echo 'el ciclo se ejecutara '.$max.' veces <br>';
while ($i <= $max) {
    echo $i++; 
}
```